# AJAX event works but not reflect PHP MYSQL result simultaneously without refresh.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Hello guys I am new to AJAX and I'm developing DB list like CRUD and one of delete feature I used with AJAX actually it deletes record but only reflect after manual refresh not simultaneously so I need your help with AJAX.

**List.php**

```
<?php 
    include "db.php";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $query = $conn->query($sql);
?>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).on('click','#btn_delete',function(){
                var uid = $(this).data("id1");
                if(confirm('Are You Sure To Delete '+uid+' ?'))
                {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'delete.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: 'uid='+uid,
                    dataType: 'text',
                    success:function(data){
                        //alert(data);
                    }
                });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Skills</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
    </tr>
        <?php
        while($row = $query->fetch_object()){
        //echo $row->name."<br>";
        ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row->uid; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->contact; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->skills; ?></td>
        <td id="edit">

            <button calss="delete_btn" type="submit" id="btn_delete" name="delete" value="DELETE" data-id1="<?php echo $row->uid; ?>">DELETE</button>
            <!-- <a href="delete.php" data-id2="<?php echo $row->uid; ?>" id="delete" alt="DELETE" >Delete</a> -->
            <a href="form.php?link=<?php echo $row->uid; ?>" value="<?php echo $row->uid; ?>" alt="UPDATE">Update</a>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

*Whenever I press Delete button it actually delete record on first hand from database that mean ajax works but simultaneously table is not refresh, deleted entry remain in table till next refresh.*

**Delete.php**

```
<?php
    include "db.php";
    $uid = $_POST['uid'];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE uid='".$uid."'";
    $conn->query($sql);
    $conn->close();
?>
<p id="check">Deleted</p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see some issues with this code and currently only partial or round about answers so I thought I would lend a hand :)

1. The dynamic rows you create inside your while loop have buttons that have a static ID across all delete buttons.

   - This could cause problems because ID's are supposed to be unique.
   - You misspelled `class`.
   - I removed the ID, corrected the spelling on class, and updated the JavaScript to use the button class instead of ID.
2. Since the button is in the table we can use it as a marker for which row to remove from the table.

   - This can be accomplished by calling [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/): `var tr = $(this).closest("tr");`
   - Once the AJAX succeeds we can now [remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) that row: `tr.remove();`
3. The [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function has gone through some changes recently as the success callback was deprecated and then removed in 3.0 see Deprecation Notice.

   - This would cause your success call to not fire as it doesn't exist in 3.0 and from your question we can see that your using version 3.2.1.
   - I have replaced the callback with the updated call.

Here is the solution I came up with:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on("click", ".btn_delete", function(){
            var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
            var uid = $(this).data("id1");

            if (confirm("Are You Sure To Delete " + uid + "?")) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "delete.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: "uid=" + uid,
                    dataType: "text",
                    done: function(data){
                        tr.remove();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Contact</th>
            <th>Skills</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        while($row = $query->fetch_object()){
        //echo $row->name."<br>";
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row->uid; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->contact; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->skills; ?></td>
            <td id="edit">
                <button class="delete_btn" type="submit" name="delete" 
                    value="DELETE" data-id1="<?php echo $row->uid; ?>">DELETE</button>
                <a href="form.php?link=<?php echo $row->uid; ?>"
                    value="<?php echo $row->uid; ?>" alt="UPDATE">Update</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

> On another note the PHP call to your MySql in `Delete.php` is susceptible to injection attacks here is some documentation on that in [PHP < 5.5](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-function.mysql-real-escape-string.html) see `Example 5.50 An example SQL Injection Attack` and in [PHP >= 5.5](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli.real-escape-string.html) as the function was deprecated in 5.5.

Comment: Edited answer to include #3 as it could also be causing issues.

Answer (score 4):

You can delete the element in the success callback function like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'delete.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'uid='+uid,
    dataType: 'text',
    success:function(data){
        //if using jquery
        //$('tr').filter(':has(td:first:contains(' + uid + '))').remove();
        $('tr').filter(function() {
            return $(this).find('td:first').text() == uid;
        }).remove();
        //if not
        var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
        var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            if (rows[i].children[0].textContent == uid) {
                table.removeChild(rows[i]);
            }    
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'delete.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: 'uid='+uid,
                dataType: 'text',
                success:function(data){
                    window.location.href = 'YOUR PAGE';
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the page to reload automatically after successful ajax call. Try This:

```
           $.ajax({
                url: 'delete.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: 'uid='+uid,
                dataType: 'text',
                success:function(data){
                    location.reload();
                }
            })
```